# Hosts file not honoring the dev sites mapping in OSX Yosemite

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, homestead, osx-yosemite

This issue has been affecting my multi-site development since months and on. My Yosemite OSX hosts file (located at `/etc/hosts` never honors these sites I put in at the top:

`192.168.10.10   blackbird.dev
192.168.10.10   saveeo.dev`

What might be wrong? To help the answerers understand the situation, I've done the following:

1. Flushed the DNS cache
2. My Homestead.yaml file looks like this below [see A]
3. Homestead destroyed and ran again (nope, no difference)
4. Computer restarted and ran again (nope, no difference)
5. If I go 192.168.10.10, one site opens up, the first one listed in .yaml
6. If I do saveeo.dev or blackbird.dev, this shows up [see B]
7. If I ping from my local machine, I get this [see C]
8. If I ping from within the box (doing homestead ssh) and then I see this. [ see D]

What is happening, help me out. I've used all my knowledge to make this work, but I just don't know what is causing this. I am not able to access my dev sites through the browser like `app.dev` and `app2.dev`. Quite frustrating.

**Appendix A**

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/aligajani/Dropbox/Vinkk_Software
      to:  /home/vagrant/Vinkk_Software

    - map: /Users/aligajani/Dropbox/hackathon
      to:  /home/vagrant/hackathon

sites:
    - map: blackbird.dev
      to:  /home/vagrant/Vinkk_Software/blackbird/public

    - map: saveeo.dev
      to:  /home/vagrant/hackathon/saveeo/public


databases:
    - homestead
    - saveeo

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

**Appendix B**

This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

**Appendix C**

```
PING saveeo.dev (127.0.53.53): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1



PING blackbird.dev (127.0.53.53): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

**Appendix D**

```
ping saveeo.dev
PING saveeo.dev (127.0.53.53) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms


ping blackbird.dev
PING blackbird.dev (127.0.53.53) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
```

Comment: Can you post your entire hosts file. It sounds like you may have a double entry.

Comment: @whoacowboy http://pastebin.com/1ixdAqB6

Comment: Try clearing your dns cache. for Yosemite  `sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches`

Comment: @whoacowboy, same, no difference.

Comment: Have you tried `vagrant destroy` then `vagrant up`? It can clear out your database, so be sure to back it up.

Comment: Yes I have done that. No difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77985/discussion-between-whoacowboy-and-ali-gajani).

Answer (score 1):

My hosts file kept on being ignored after I edited in text edit. I tried several ways to fix the line endings, added IPv6 entries to the existing IPv4 entries with no success. The only solution that worked is using this free GUI plugin to edit hosts file.

https://github.com/specialunderwear/Hosts.prefpane/blob/master/README.mdown

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue, out of the blue... For some reason the hosts file was corrupted (line endings) and by using that tool I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an issue with your mac dns resolution and nothing to do with vagrant.

Check out https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158117/os-x-10-10-1-etc-hosts-private-etc-hosts-file-is-being-ignored-and-not-resol

Comment: Nope, didn't work. At least I found out one thing. pinging tells me it resolves to an entirely different IP. :-(